# Defined an empty array in c

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

What actually happened in following program, I have defined an empty array `int arr[];` in code and with the GCC compiler, but the compiler doesn't give an error. It's successfully worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct st
{
        int i;
        int arr[];
}ST,*ptr;

int main()
{
        ST s1;
        ptr p1= (ptr)malloc(sizeof(ST)+4*sizeof(int));

        p1->i=10;
        p1->arr[0]=1;
        p1->arr[3] = 1;

        printf("%d\n",p1->arr[3]);
        printf("%ld\n", sizeof(s1));
}
```

`C` language not allowed **undefined array length**. but **GCC compiler** allowed. Why?

Just curious, what actually happens?

Comment: C standard allows this. Search for "flexible array member".

Comment: [Flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), two suggestions: don't cast `malloc` and don't hide pointers with `typedef`s

Comment: As the last member of the struct, it is useful when the struct stores a variable amount of data.

Comment: @AlterMann Thank you sir, I not aware this topic..

Comment: It's a [C99 feature](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.2.1); not available in out-of-date C compilers (notably some versions of Microsoft Visual Studio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's valid and allowed since [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). It's called [*flexible array member*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) - useful to make the last member of the struct variable-length and it must be the last member of the struct if used.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at a C99 feature, [Flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). If the array is defined at the end of the struct, then you will define its size during allocation via malloc, by allocating a bigger chunk of memory.

for an array of size `len`:

```
struct st *mySt = malloc(sizeof(struct st) + len * sizeof(mySt->arr[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

**C99**, the structure of the last element allows the size of the array is unknown, which is called a **flexible array member**, but in front of the structure of a flexible array member must have at least one other member.

**Flexible array members** allowed to structure contains an array of variable size. This size of the structure **sizeof** returns do not include a flexible array of memory. Structure comprising a flexible array member using `malloc ()` function allocates memory dynamically and allocates memory should be larger than the size of the structure to accommodate the expected size of the flexible array.

The basic model

```
typedef struct st
{
        int i;
        int arr[];
}ST,*ptr;
```

Tested under linux gcc about operating results for the structure, the last element of an array, and an array of undefined length, operating results consistent with theory, this is a bit like a c ++ class member functions, member functions is not occupied class space size. Well, this flexible array, there is the role of what is.